# Am I able to ask questions about retro computing yet?

Tags: discussion

It seems that this part of the stack exchange still isn't fit for purpose.

[image: Retrocomputing on the Stack Exchange]

Okay so there may be an exaggeration somewhere in there, but I think there is still a lot of truth in there.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Wait… Aren't you the one who posted the question asking for help with the old, half-finished text adventure game you found in an archive somewhere? Is it about that?

Comment: Well you could try, a lot of people have done so.  Your last action appears to be a comment last November.  Just because your previous two attempts were closed, doesn't mean you can't try again.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're saying. It sounds like you're saying that you've posted a retrocomputing question, but it wasn't well-received? Am I understanding you right? And it also sounds like you're saying something needs to be changed, is that right? But you're not saying what the question you posted is, or what happened to it, or what you'd like to see happen. So that's why I don't understand exactly what you're saying. Could you please clarify these things?

Answer (score 5):

It could well be that the Retrocomputing SE has failed to be "fit for purpose" at times, but you provide no real evidence of this here. Without links to specific questions where we can determine what went wrong (or right) in the close vote process, all we know is that a question ostensibly on the topic of retrocomputing got closed. But since we expect in every SE that we will occasionally get poor quality questions that should be closed, "some questions were closed" is in no way evidence that any particular SE is not working well.

From my own search for evidence on whether here one "[can] access legitimate questions about computing on retro machines" and whether or not it "[s]eems hard to post C64 questions on Stack Exchange without upsetting people," I offer the following heavily-upvoted questions directly pertaining to programming* on the C64. The figures in parentheses are the upvotes and downvotes for each.

- [How did Commodore's anti-Microsoft Easter Egg work?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4416/7208) (+104, -0)
- [Why do programmable sound generators like SID include a noise generator?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2573/7208) (+37, -0)
- [How did C64 games handle music during gameplay?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11825/7208) (+38, -1)
- [Why are C64 games inconsistent with which joystick port they use?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11097/7208) (+34, -0)
- [Why does the C64's LIST command choke on REM statements with a Shift+L?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7208) (+29, -0)
- [C64: Why is POS(π) faster than POS(0)?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4808/7208) (+29, -0)
- [Why does waggling the joystick of a C64 cause errors loading from tape?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4908/7208) (+21, -0)
- [How was digital sound playback achieved on the Commodore 64?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/325/7208) (+19, -0)
- [What's a good way to implement this “splashing water” effect on the C64?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7541/7208) (+18, -0)
- [How to move sprites to the border on c64?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/97/7208) (+17, -0)

All of these questions have received good answers (>10 upvotes) and all but one have received multiple answers. I would suggest reading through them to help get a sense of how to ask a good question, if you feel your or other questions are getting closed unfairly. In particular, pay attention to how they, in SE style, can elicit reasonably specific, non-opinion answers.

And of course if you don't understand why particular questions are (or are not) being closed, feel free to post links to those, along with your arguments about what's wrong, as further questions to this meta.

---

*I chose "programming" here because your question mentions "somebody who posted a C64 question on the original stack exchange," presumably [SO](https://stackoverflow.com), where people would be posting programming questions, and "upvote attempts to program on the C64" again indicating that the topic was programming in particular. Retrocomputing also covers non-programming use of old systems, and there are plenty of good questions about the C64 in that area as well, though the non-programming area does, unsurprisingly, have a slightly higher incidence of poor questions.

Answer (score 2):

As to your question:

> Am I able to ask questions about retro computing yet?

Yes, you are able, feel free.